# How to use Fingale futures to an existing Restful webservice

Tags: scala, rest, finagle

I have a webservice running on jboss server. I can't change it to netty because i'm using other features of jboss. But i want to use finagles futures from the client. Is there a way ?

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?  Generally you ask a question when a specific problem is encountered otherwise you run the risk of the question getting closed.  On top of that, I don't see how the technology used in the http container vm (async vs non-async) should have any bearing on the technology used in the client vm.

Answer (score 0):

The `Future` class used in Finagle is part of [Twitter's `util` project](https://github.com/twitter/util), which is open source. `com.twitter.util.Future` is usable on its own within any project that adds `util-core` as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a finagle client to make calls to an HTTP [or other RPC protocol] webservice. It doesn't matter how the service is implemented as along as it uses the protocol correctly. If you are using Java, this link should give you details on how to build a finagle client for an HTTP service: https://github.com/twitter/finagle#Building%20a%20Client%20in%20Java

Here's some sample code to for a more elaborate finagle HTTP client: https://github.com/twitter/finagle/blob/master/finagle-example/src/main/scala/com/twitter/finagle/example/http/HttpClient.scala